# How can I tell my code that it has a "Flush"?

Tags: java

I'm suppose to create a code that recognizes if my hand has the same card faces

```
public static boolean sameFace(String hand) {

hand = "s9s7s2sQsK";
char f = hand.charAt(0);

if( hand.charAt(0)==hand.charAt(2) && hand.charAt(0)==hand.charAt(4) 
&& hand.charAt(0)==hand.charAt(6) && hand.charAt(0)==hand.charAt(8));

return (hand.charAt(0) == hand.charAt(2) && hand.charAt(0) == hand.charAt(4) 
   && hand.charAt(0) == hand.charAt(6) && hand.charAt(0) == hand.charAt(8));

   sameface = hand;
   if (hand==true;)

   return (hand==true;) ; 

 }
```

As can be seen above, if all positions are the same characters, it comes true(False, if even one isn't the same.) How can I then use the result of that "return" to let my program recognize it has the same faces or not? If that is even possible.

From what i know, based on my code, it's saying "Yes, positions x=y=z are the same" how can I then tell it  "Since they are the same, they have the same card faces."

I tried to put this at the end

```
   sameface = hand;
   if (hand==true;)
       return (hand==true;) ;
```

Basically I'm trying to say that when the "hand" return statement is true, then samefaces is true. Meaning that the faces are the same. And if it's false it'll return false.

Comment: You can sort the cards by value and check are these cards have the same "color". However, this kind of checking the "values" of the hand is inefficient. Try your search engine and see how hand checking is implemented in many ways.

Comment: You have a `;` after the `if` statement. You also have a `;` inside the arg to `return` - does that even compile?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I'm trying to say that when the "hand" return statement is true, then samefaces is true. Meaning that the faces are the same. And if it's false it'll return false.

You do that simply by returning the result of the expression:

```
public static boolean sameFace(String hand) {
    char f = hand.charAt(0);
    return f == hand.charAt(2) &&
           f == hand.charAt(4) &&
           f == hand.charAt(6) &&
           f == hand.charAt(8);
}
```

Or if you want to be friendly to a different number of cards, use a loop:

```
public static boolean sameFace(String hand) {
    char f = hand.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 2, len = hand.length(); i < len; i += 2) {
        if (f != hand.charAt(i)) {
            // Not a match
            return false;
        }
    }

    // All matched
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hmm do i just put public static boolean sameFace(String hand) {
    char f = hand.charAt(0);
    return f == hand.charAt(2) &&
           f == hand.charAt(4) &&
           f == hand.charAt(6) &&
           f == hand.charAt(8);
}

after my code?

Hmm i tried your code and there's and error.

says "can not find symbol variable length"

Comment: @WaterIsScience: I forgot that `length` is a method in Java. Fixed. (You could trivially have figured that out on your own.)